# Algorithm to Get Directions

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, geo

I have a consisting of points along a gpx route by distance. I want to use this to generate directions based upon the underlying trail data I have. It works great except that the inaccuracies of the data cause some gaps where the buffer on the gpx track doesn't find any trails. I want to ignore these sections if the gap is smaller than a certain unit.

```
=========================
  miles  | nearest trail
=========================
   1     |   a
   2     |   a
   3     |   a
   4     |   none *assume it is actually 'a' 
   5     |   a
   6     |   a
   7     |   none
   8     |   none
   9     |   none
   10    |   b    *assume it is actually 'none'
   11    |   none
   12    |   none
   13    |   c
   14    |   c
   15    |   c
```

I want to get this:

```
=====================
 trail   |  travel for
=====================
   a     |   6 miles
   none  |   6 miles
   c     |   3 miles
```

I am looking for some suggestions on how to do this as I keep running into problems. I currently have the data in a mysql table and am using php.

Comment: You need to get much more specific in regards to when/why you assume a value to actually be a prior value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Hidden Markov model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_markov_model). If you feed it the probabilities of being on track x after being on track y previously (so the probability for x=y would be pretty high and low otherwise), and the probability of recording track y when actually on track x (which would be high for x=y, lowish for y=none, and low otherwise), you can calculate a most probable actual path based on the observations with the [Viterbi algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it sounds like you need a map, [a shortest path map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) to be specific. It sounds like you have some code, but without posting it there is not much I can say about it.